# Replace Characters in Variable with Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, variables, google-tag-manager

Please help me to fix this issue.

Inside Google Tag Manager, I have a CSS selector variable on DOM. I need to remove the characters (Rp.) and (.) in the variable.

Example:

> DOM_PriceDiscount: Rp. 150.000.000

I'm using this to replace the characters:

```
function() {
var DOM_PriceDiscount = {{DOM_PriceDiscount}};
var DOM_PriceDiscount_1 = DOM_PriceDiscount.replace("Rp. ", "");
var fullPrice = DOM_PriceDiscount_1.replace(".", "");
return fullPrice;   }
```

But when I see the result, I just can replace one "." and "Rp. ", like this:

> 150000.000

Can you help me to replace another "."? Because I just want to use:

> 150000000

Thank you.

Comment: What CSS do you mean? May you update the snippet to be a [mcve]?

Comment: Hi, I have changed it @evolutionxbox

Comment: Have you looked into using `replaceAll`?

Comment: Do you mean it?
var fullPrice = DOM_PriceDiscount_1.replaceAll(".", "") @evolutionxbox

Comment: Does that do what you want?